# SAX Parser not reading after newline

Tags: java, sax

I am using the SAX parser to parse preformed text as listed below:

```
<content><![CDATA[(a) Definitions. 
   (i) term - Definition of term
   (ii) term 2 - Definition of term 2
   (iii) term 3 - Definition of term 3]]>
</content>
```

My handler

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length){
    if (content) {
        contentText = new String(ch, start, length));
    }   
}
```

However I am only getting the first line "(a) Definitions. " in my character buffer. The other lines are not being copied. How can I access the missing lines?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [SAX parser specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html), you may be getting multiple callbacks for `characters`, representing chunks of the same character block. You should combine consecutive ones into a single string.

> The Parser will call [`characters`] method to report each chunk of character data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the characters in any single event must come from the same external entity so that the Locator provides useful information.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that `characters()` will be called with the *complete* text. You need to collate the results of each call, and check the string once you've processed the end element.

Comment: So I should use a string buffer to read the characters till it's done.
Thanks